# Mysql_query for all items inside array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an `array()` in php. I want to search through mysql database simultaneously for all array items.
For example cars array as below:

```
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
```

Besides Array size is variable. I need to search inside mysql database and see *if specific row contains all array values or not?*

something like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Person Where personCar contains $cars[0] AND $cars[1] AND $cars[2]);
```

personCar is a String. For example "Volvo, BMW, Toyota, Benz, ..."
Besides Array size is variable.
I would appreciate if you help.
I've thought of for loop and foreach loop but don't know the method in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$tmp = array();
foreach ($cars as $car) {
 $tmp[] = "personCar LIKE '%".$car."%'";
}
$tmp = implode(" AND ", $tmp); //" OR " if you want to get a person which owns any of those cars

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Person Where {$tmp};");
```

Comment: *Actually, you could use regular expressions, but I don't think that it will improve performance.

Comment: Thanks genius! Works Perfect. You know how to answer the answer! You sure know.